# Javascript returns [object HTMLSpanElement]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple game for selling anchovies. I have an upgrade to buy a small fishing net. The fishing net costs a certain amount of anchovies, so I subtract that number from the total and then rewrite using innerHTML. I want this small net to add 1 anchovy every second, so I use window.setInterval. However, now every second [object HTMLSpanElement] is written to the page.

What do I do?

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Bj6M5/1/

And here is the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var anchovies = 0;
var money = 0;

function goFish(num) {
    anchovies = anchovies + num;
    money = 0.433 * anchovies;
    var money_rounded;
    money_rounded = money.toFixed(2);
    if (anchovies != 1) {
        document.getElementById("anchovies").innerHTML = anchovies + " anchovies";
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("anchovies").innerHTML = "1 anchovy";
    }
    document.title = "$" + money_rounded + " - Anchovy Bros.";
}

function buySmallNet(){
var smallnet_price = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,smallnets));     
    if (anchovies >= smallnet_price) {                                   
        smallnets = smallnets + 1;                                   
        anchovies = anchovies - smallnet_price; 
        if (smallnets != 1) {                       
            document.getElementById("smallnets").innerHTML = smallnets + " small nets";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("smallnets").innerHTML = "1 small net";
        }  
        document.getElementById("anchovies").innerHTML = anchovies + " anchovies";  
    }

    else {
        alert("You don't have enough anchovies!");
    }
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    goFish(smallnets);
}, 1000);
</script>
    <title>$0 - Anchovy Bros.</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="goFish(1);">FISH!</button>
<br>
<span id="anchovies"></span>

<div style="float:right;" id="upgrades">
    <center>
    <button onclick="buySmallNet();">small fishing net</button>
    <br>
    <span>costs 15 anchovies</span>
    <br>
    <span id="smallnets"></span>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: problem was that _smallnets_ wasnt initialised. do this:
`var smallnets = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `goFish(smallnets)`. smallnets is the id of an element, so you're passing that element. You're expecting a number in `goFish` and do all kinds of calculations and assignments, which obviously fail, because it's an element and not a number. In the end, you're outputting `anchovies`, which is now assigned that element, instead of the result of a calculation.

So there's a missing links somewhere where you need to convert the element to a number, which should probably be the contents of the element (being the number of small nets in posession).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this line:

```
goFish(smallnets);
```

You haven't declared a `smallnets` variable anywhere, but you have an element in your markup with the `id` `"smallnets"` which is a `span`. Most browsers create global variables for elements with `id` values, where the name of the variable is the `id` and the value is the DOM element.

Then in `goFish`, this line:

```
anchovies = anchovies + num;
```

is (on the first pass):

```
anchovies = 0 + a_span_element;
```

Since the `span` can't be reasonably converted to a number, it's converted to a string, which is `"[object HTMLSpanElement]"`. Then the `0` is converted to a string and you have `"0[object HTMLSpanElement]"`.

And then the next time the interval fires, you add another copy of `"[object HTMLSpanElement]"` to it, etc., etc.

If your goal is to use the *text* of the `span`, you want:

```
goFish(smallnets.innerHTML);
```

or better

```
goFish(parseInt(smallnets.innerHTML, 10));
```

or even better, don't rely on the global created via the `id`:

```
goFish(parseInt(document.getElementById("smallnets").innerHTML, 10));
```

You'll also want to put `0` or something in the span, e.g.:

```
<span id="smallnets">0</span>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That was a lot easier than I expected, sorry I've just never run into that problem before